# Browser compatibiliy code does not compile in ts

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add this to the bottom of a .ts file but I get an error in VS2012 [under: **if (!Object.construct)** ] that construct and extend are not defined. Solutions?

```
if (!Object.construct) {
  Object.construct = function(base) {
    var instance = Object.create(base);
    if (instance.initialize)
      instance.initialize.apply(instance, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return instance;
  }
}

if (!Object.extend) {
  Object.extend = function(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
      if (source.hasOwnProperty(property))
        destination[property] = source[property];
    }
    return destination;
  };
}
```

tried this:

```
interface Object {
    extend(destination, source): any;
    construct(base): any;
}

class Game { etc//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the Object interface:

```
interface Object {
    extend(destination, source): any;
    construct(base): any;
}
```

Place that in the root context of your code (not inside a module). You should also add in typing, even if it's only defining the arguments as "any"

Comment: Did you place the interface inside of a module? It works for me, and that's the only reason I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

You would not want to extend the Object interface here.  This is what gets inherited by all object instances (i.e. methods on all objects such as toString and valueOf).  From the above, looks like you are trying to adds statics to the Object constructor (i.e. similar to methods such as Object.create and Object.keys).

The Object constructor function is declared as a var in the lib.d.ts file.  You cannot reopen & extend a declared variable in the 0.8.x releases of TypeScript.  The easiest solution would be to make a copy of lib.d.ts for your project and modify the "declare var Object" statement to add your extra functions.  If you reference your own lib.d.ts file (i.e. "\\ " in your project files, it will use this instead of the default lib.d.ts.

Comment: actually just doing that had duplicate signatures so I just added the 1st answers code and it worked